# map trough array of objects then use filter to remove dupes

Tags: javascript, arrays

So my question is if i have an array of objects

```
var arr = [{"id":1, "image":"sport.jpg", "tag_name":"Sport","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":true, "my_favourites":true},
{"id":2, "image":"sport.jpg", "tag_name":"Fudbal","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":true, "my_favourites":true},
{"id":3,  "image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"Premier League","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":false,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":4, "image":"sport.jpg", "tag_name":"La liga","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":5, "image":"sport.jpg", "tag_name":"Real Madrid","tag_type":"Fudabal","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":6, "image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"UEFA","tag_type":"Tim","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":7,"image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"Juve","tag_type":"Liga","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":false},
{"id":8,"image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"Barca","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":false,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":9,"image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"Sport","tag_type":"Fudbal","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":true}
]
```

I map trough array and then filter it for removing dupes,(tag_type) but just can't wrap my head around it.

```
var filtred = arr.map(function(item) { return item.tag_type;
  }).filter(function(filt,index) {
    return filt.indexOf(filt) == index;
});
```

result of filter is ["Takmicenje"]

map is working correctly

```
["Takmicenje", "Takmicenje", "Takmicenje", "Takmicenje", "Fudabal", "Tim", "Liga", "Takmicenje", "Fudbal"]
```

result of filter is

```
["Takmicenje"]
```

I want to get array of

```
['Takmicenje','Fudbal','Tim','Liga'];
```

Comment: "can't wrap my head around it." That's not a question. What is your question?

Comment: Is the code doing what you want? I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: `filt.indexOf(filt)` doesn't make a lot of sense in that context

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use filter in the right way:

```js
var arr = [{"id":1, "image":"sport.jpg", "tag_name":"Sport","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":true, "my_favourites":true},
{"id":2, "image":"sport.jpg", "tag_name":"Fudbal","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":true, "my_favourites":true},
{"id":3,  "image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"Premier League","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":false,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":4, "image":"sport.jpg", "tag_name":"La liga","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":5, "image":"sport.jpg", "tag_name":"Real Madrid","tag_type":"Fudabal","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":6, "image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"UEFA","tag_type":"Tim","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":7,"image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"Juve","tag_type":"Liga","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":false},
{"id":8,"image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"Barca","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":false,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":9,"image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"Sport","tag_type":"Fudbal","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":true}
];

var filtred = arr.map(function(item) { return item.tag_type;
  }).filter(function(filt, ind, currentArray) {
    return ind == currentArray.indexOf(filt);
});
console.log(filtred);
```

Answer (score 2):

## The Answers:

### Answer #1 -- Pretty & Dynamic:

```
 let result = [...new Set(arr.map(item=>item.tag_type))];
```

### Answer #2 -- Fast (5X as fast as the top answer)

```
let tagTypes = {};
arr.forEach(item => tagTypes[item.tag_type] = true)
let result = Object.keys(tagTypes)
```

## The explanation:

Most of the existing answers are perfectly functional, especially for this small of a data-set. The problems begin to arise when you have thousands of items to iterate over, so let’s talk performance.
Every response thus far has used `Array.prototype.indexOf` inside some kind of loop. The problem with this is that `indexOf` itself is a loop.
As a result, @quirimmo’s response iterates 11 times and @SeanGregory’s iterates 10 times.

Below, I will explain how to achieve the desired effect without nesting loops.

### Answer #1

Let’s break this apart:

```
 let result = [...new Set(arr.map(item=>item.tag_type))]
```

In the center of this, we have the `map` . This should be familiar.

```
let allTagTypes = arr.map(item=>item.tag_type)
```

The ES6 Set is an iterable object which, “lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.”
This means when you construct a Set, passing it an array with duplicate items, the resulting Set will essentially remove the duplicates and only store each item once.
As such, we can do the following and get a Set of unique tag types:

```
let filteredTagTypes = new Set(allTagTypes);
```

This is great, but we want the results as an Array, not a Set. We can convert this Set into an array using the Spread Operator.

```
let result = [...filteredTagTypes];
// ["Takmicenje","Fudabal","Tim","Liga","Fudbal"]
```

That’s it!

Notes: The question was about how to filter out duplicates from an array of property values. This solution will work for all types of values. For the asker’s specific scenario (the values always being strings), Answer #2 is considerably better.

As it turns out, the construction of a Set is a relatively heavy process. Performance-wise, we end up in about the same place as with `indexOf`. It's a one-liner though, so why not? :)

Now for numero dos!

### Answer #2

This one is a bit more succinct.

```
let tagTypes = {};
arr.forEach(item => tagTypes[item.tag_type] = true)
let result = Object.keys(tagTypes)
```

First, we create an object that will hold our tag types.

```
let tagTypes = {};
```

Next, we loop through each item in the array. 
For each item, we set a property on the `tagTypes` object with a key of the item’s `tag_name` and a value of `true`. If the property is already there, it’s simply overwritten with the same thing. If not, it’s added to the object.

When the loop is complete, `tagTypes` will be an object that looks like this:

```
{
     "Takmicenje":true,
     "Fudabal":true,
     "Tim":true,
     "Liga":true,
     "Fudbal":true
}
```

We can now get an Array of `tagTypes`' keys using Object.keys().

```
let result = Object.keys(tagTypes)
// ["Takmicenje","Fudabal","Tim","Liga","Fudbal"]
```

That’s *two* iterations. Vroom vroom!

### The Results

Here’s a snippet running each function and a JSPerf performance comparison if you’re interested:

JSPerf: https://jsperf.com/unique-array-items-from-properties

```js
let arr = [{"id":1, "image":"sport.jpg", "tag_name":"Sport","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":true, "my_favourites":true},
{"id":2, "image":"sport.jpg", "tag_name":"Fudbal","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":true, "my_favourites":true},
{"id":3,  "image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"Premier League","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":false,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":4, "image":"sport.jpg", "tag_name":"La liga","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":5, "image":"sport.jpg", "tag_name":"Real Madrid","tag_type":"Fudabal","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":6, "image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"UEFA","tag_type":"Tim","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":7,"image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"Juve","tag_type":"Liga","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":false},
{"id":8,"image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"Barca","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":false,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":9,"image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"Sport","tag_type":"Fudbal","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":true}
];

function withSet(arr){ // Answer #1
 return [...new Set(arr.map(item=>item.tag_type))]
}

function withObject(arr){ // Answer #2
 let tagTypes = {};
 arr.forEach(item => tagTypes[item.tag_type] = true)
 return Object.keys(tagTypes)
}

console.log('With Object', withObject(arr))
console.log('With Set', withSet(arr))
```

Note: in the question, it says the desired result is `['Takmicenje','Fudbal','Tim','Liga']`,  but the actual result with duplicates removed is `[“Takmicenje", "Fudabal", "Tim", "Liga", "Fudbal"]`.

Comment: This one takes advantage of hashing, it is indeed a faster solution. However the previous best solution was mine (`O (n log n)` rather than `O(n^2)`), not sure why you decided to omit it.

Comment: @arboreal84 I only included quirimmo's answer as a general example of the performance implications of nesting loops, not because it was the fastest. Either way, the question was about using a filter, so it's totally fair for that answer to be on top

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want an array of `tag_type` with duplicates removed. Here you go

```js
var arr = [{"id":1, "image":"sport.jpg", "tag_name":"Sport","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":true, "my_favourites":true},
{"id":2, "image":"sport.jpg", "tag_name":"Fudbal","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":true, "my_favourites":true},
{"id":3,  "image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"Premier League","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":false,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":4, "image":"sport.jpg", "tag_name":"La liga","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":5, "image":"sport.jpg", "tag_name":"Real Madrid","tag_type":"Fudabal","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":6, "image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"UEFA","tag_type":"Tim","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":7,"image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"Juve","tag_type":"Liga","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":false},
{"id":8,"image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"Barca","tag_type":"Takmicenje","my_feed":false,"my_favourites":true},
{"id":9,"image":"sport.jpg","tag_name":"Sport","tag_type":"Fudbal","my_feed":true,"my_favourites":true}
];

var filtered = arr.map(function(item) {
                      return item.tag_type;
                  })
                  .reduce(function(result, currentTagType) {
                      if (result.indexOf(currentTagType) === -1)
                          result.push(currentTagType);
                      return result;
                  }, []);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: @arboreal84  And your suggestion?

Comment: @arboreal84 your solution would perform the worst. Because you first have to sort it, then removing the next items that are equal like you said, **removing items in the middle of a list IS expensive**. Calm down there bud

Comment: @orboreal84 Why don't you post your implementation and see if runs faster than the other answers including mine, if it does, I'll give you a +1 even though I did not give you the downvote

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this :

```
var filtred = arr.map(function(item) { return item.tag_type;
  }).filter(function(filt,index, mapped) { 
    return mapped.indexOf(filt) == index;
});
```

Enjoy

Comment: It's maybe not a problem for this issue, but you're right, store data in a map will work far faster than my answer

Answer (score -1):

https://jsperf.com/unique-array-items-from-properties-2/1

Implemented a recursive solution.  Pretty darn fast.  and [ES6 has O(1) memory complexity for tail end recursion](http://benignbemine.github.io/2015/07/19/es6-tail-calls/)

Recursion with indexOf

```
function recurse(arr, newArr){
  let el = arr.shift();
  if (el === undefined){
    return newArr;  
  }else{
    if (newArr.indexOf(el.tag_name) === -1){
      newArr.push(el.tag_name);
    }
    recurse(arr, newArr);
  }
}
recurse(arr, []);
```

Recursion using an object (based on mccallofthewild's answer)

```
  function withRecursionAndObject(arr, newObj){
    let el = arr.shift();
    if (el === undefined){
      return Object.keys(newObj);  
    }else{
      newObj[el.tag_type] = true;
      withRecursionAndObject(arr, newObj);
    }
  }
```

Using While

```
let i = arr.length;
var filtered = [];
while(i--){
  if (filtered.indexOf(arr[i].tag_name) === -1){
    filtered.push(array[i].tag_name);
  }
}
```

https://jsperf.com/filter-vs-while-vs-lodash-vs-sort

Comment: Would a for loop be faster? I have to imagine it would.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: `while` iterates over all items. `indexOf` also iterates over all items in worst case scenario. For an input of `n` items, time complexity is `O(n^2)`. It's still the same.

Comment: whoops. I missed something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145242/discussion-between-sean-gregory-and-arboreal84).

Comment: @SeanGregory I think that you got a bit confused. You should add the element if it's not present (so `=== -1`) and if you you have to push just the `tag_name` not all the object (otherwise your check then doesn't work either). 
here your jsfiddle working: https://jsfiddle.net/og8pm1m8/

Comment: yeah, i just saw that.  it seems you can't do indexOf on an object in an array, probably due to references?

Comment: Nope, you have it.  Nice!

Comment: @SeanGregory Take a look at my answer again, I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, I saw where I goofed.  Want to check out my new  iteration?

Comment: Oh thought you were quirimmo, I definitely understood what you meant.  I just would rather create the solution around the problem instead of assuming one is the best.  Chances are if I'm dealing with data that big, I'd want to find ways to partition it, stream it, etc..  Would it not be like the same concept of database indexes, as in you shouldn't implement a mapping unless you know you need it?

Comment: @arboreal84 You take this too seriously. It is way off topic. You even deleted your old comment and post a new one to get rid of those downvotes and was making such a fuss about getting downvoted, chill out for a bit.

Comment: I corrected all the feedback. Stack Overflow answers should be taken seriously, people use Stack Overflow for learning and for work.